# Losing SQLite DB data after application upgrade - how it can be?

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

In my application I'm storing data in SQLite database. And from time to time I'm releasing new versions of application, but never changing database schema. One of my customers reported me that each time he upgrades application he's losing all data.

I have thoroughly investigated my code and couldn't find how it's possible that user lost data.

Basically my code related to SQLite database handling looks like:

```
public final class Storage
{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="my.db"; //db name
    /**
     * database tables creation scripts
     */
    private static final String DATA1_CREATE="create table if not exists ...";
    private static final String DATA2_CREATE="create table if not exists ...";
    private static final String IDX_DATA1_CREATE="create index if not exists...";
    private static final String IDX_DATA2_CREATE="create index if not exists ...";

    /**
     * Constructs Storage object and if necessary creates tables
     * @param context application environment (Android context)
     */
    public Storage(Context context)
    {
        database=context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        database.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            database.execSQL(DATA1_CREATE);
            database.execSQL(IDX_DATA1_CREATE);
            database.execSQL(DATA2_CREATE);
            database.execSQL(IDX_DATA2_CREATE);
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't create database", e);
            database=null;
            return;
        }
        database.endTransaction();
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getDatabase()
    {
        return database;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        if(database!=null)
            database.close();
    }
}
```

I see only drawback in my code that I don't extend class `SQLiteOpenHelper` - can it be potential problem and lead to losing data during application upgrade?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I just experienced this using the internal testing track in play store. Would also be interested if you ever found an answer, the data entry for my app is kinda tedious

Answer (score 0):

create sqlitehelper class and write necessary codes in onupgrade()

Comment: onUpgrade called each time during application upgrade - but if I never change database schema that means onUpgrade() will be empty. If so does it make a sense?